# Spinner Adapter keeps on reverting

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

The spinner works fine, when clicked it has a drop down menu that has checkboxes next to it. My problem is when I click on a check box it ticks, but when I close the spinner and open it back op again, the box is unticked. I want the boxes to remain checked how can I do this?
Here's my code.

```
ArrayList<StateVO> listbtop = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < btoppings.length; i++) {
        StateVO stateVO = new StateVO();
        stateVO.setTitle(btoppings[i]);
        stateVO.setSelected(false);
        listbtop.add(stateVO);
    }
 MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(Guest.this, 0, listbtop);
        spinnerbtop.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

And Here's my Adapter Class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<StateVO> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<StateVO> listState;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private boolean isFromView = false;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<StateVO> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listState = (ArrayList<StateVO>) objects;
        this.myAdapter = this;

    }




    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTitle());
        // To check weather checked event fire from getview() or user input
        isFromView = true;
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());
        isFromView = false;

        if ((position == 0)) {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the checked state in your object "StateVO", could you try this implementation of getCustomView ?

```
public View getCustomView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewHolder holder;
  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    convertView = layoutInflator.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, null);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.mTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
    holder.mCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

    holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        listState.get((Integer) holder.mCheckBox.getTag()).setSelected(isChecked);
      }
    });
    convertView.setTag(holder);
  } else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  holder.mCheckBox.setTag(position);

  holder.mTextView.setText(listState.get(position).getTitle());
  holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(listState.get(position).isSelected());

  return convertView;
}
```